# Add columns to a DataGridView that belongs to a custom User Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, user-controls

I created a new project in Visual Studio as a Windows Forms Control Library ("LibraryProject") in order to create custom controls. Specifically I needed a DataGridView with a ContextMenuStrip with specific menuItems to do specific things on Click, so as to use it as a .dll file in the main project("MainProject"). I created a UserControl in "LibraryProject", added the controls and modified them. The .dll file is loaded into "MainProject", my custom controls are included in the Toolbox, I can drag them into a form or another UserControl but the problem is that I cannot have access to the DataGridView and I cannot see the ContextMenuStrip. 
I need this pair to use it in many forms with different DataGridView columns. But I cannot add columns now.
What goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought of giving your `UserControl` a method to add columns to your `DataGridView`? Something along the lines of

```
public bool AddColumns(DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn)
{
    if (dgvColumn == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgvColumn);
    return true;
}
```

Check for `null` to avoid `NullReferenceException` and return a value that the calling method can work with.